# Retain successfully transformed rows in the event of runtime error in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error

When applying a string manipulation function on Pandas data frame column whose length is north of a million rows. Due to some bad data in between it fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Is there a way I can save the progress made so far on the column?

Let's say the manipulation function is:

```
def clean_strings(strg):
    strg = strg.lower() #lower
    return strg
```

And is applied to the data frame as

```
df_sample['clean_content'] = df_sample['content'].apply(clean_strings)
```

Where `'content'` is the column with strings and `'clean_content'` is the new column added.

Please suggest other approaches. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I can save the progress made so far on the column?

Unfortunately not, these function calls are meant to act atomically on the dataframe, meaning either the entire operation succeeds, or fails. I'm assuming the `str.lower` is just a representative example, you're actually doing much more in your function. That means that this is a job for *exception handling*.

```
def clean_string(row):
    try:
        return row.lower()
    except AttributeError:
        return row
```

If a particular record fails, you can handle the raised exception inside the function itself, controlling what is returned in that case.

You'd call the function appropriately -

```
df_sample['clean_content'] = df_sample['content'].apply(clean_string)
```

Note that `content` is a column of `object`s, and objects generally offer very poor performance in terms of vectorised operations. I'd recommend performing a cast to string -

```
df_sample['content'] = df_sample['content'].astype(str)
```

After this, consider using pandas' vectorised `.str` accessor functions in place of `clean_string`.

For reference, if all you want to do is lowercase your string column, use `str.lower` -

```
df_sample['content'] = df_sample['content'].astype(str).str.lower()
```

Note that, for an object column, you can still use the `.str` accessor. However, non-string elements will be coerced to `NaN` -

```
df_sample['content'] = df_sample['content'].str.lower()  # assuming `content` is of `object` type
```

Comment: @coldspeed Thank you. You are right, the example is just an example here. However, my question is why can't I access the in-memory variable anymore, is it flushed in garbage collection?

Comment: @OnlyPython Yes, the intermediate results are discarded as they are never assigned back.

Answer (score 1):

First use map as your input is only 1 column and map is faster than apply

```
df_sample['clean_content']= df_sample['content'].map(clean_strings)
```

Secondly just type cast your column to string type to run your function

```
df['content'] = df['content'].astype(str)

def clean_strings(strg):
    strg= strg.lower() #lower
    return strg
```

Comment: Thanks! but the question is about retaining the progress made if an error such as this occurs during runtime, in a dynamically typed language such as Python. Also, I don't agree with the map vs apply argument, but that's a different discussion.